# Use of Index to Improve Speed of Aggregate functions in select query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-administration

I need to create a new table with sum aggregates of the measures columns in source table.
The Source table is very huge.

eg. Source Table

```
Category | Product | Sales
A        | P1      | 100 
B        | P2      | 200
C        | P3      | 300
```

Query is like :

```
SELECT Category, 
       Product, 
       SUM(Sales) 
FROM source_table 
GROUP BY Category.
```

There is no where condition.

Will indexing help in speeding up the process?
Any alternate mechanism for speeding the query?

Comment: maybe. You need to run `EXPLAIN` on your query to see what the slowdowns are... just `EXPLAIN` followed by your query.

Comment: We the output of the explain statement. Run the following command in MySQL and post the output to the question: EXPLAIN SELECT Category, 
           Product, 
           SUM(Sales) 
    FROM source_table 
    GROUP BY Category

Comment: The output of explain statement is :
id| select_type| table| type| possible_keys| key| key_len| ref| rows| Extra|


1| SIMPLE| new_isis_indirect| index| NULL| idx_new_indirect| 1915| NULL| 182753| 
  
'

Comment: Rather than paste output into a comment, it's better to edit your original question and put it there so that we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to add an index on Category since it is in the GROUP BY clause. But you're doing a full table dump, so it might just be slow.

Probably a better strategy is to create a new table for the sales report and populated it based on your business needs. If it can be updated only daily, then schedule a stored procedure to run nightly to repopulate it. If it needs to reflect the current state of the table, then you can use triggers to update the report table as the base table is updated. Or you could run a separate query at the application level to update the report table when your base table is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are a tricky tool. If you're planning to add an index to a column of your table, you should consider at the very least:

1- How many different values do I have in this column.
2- How's the proportion between the total number of record and the number of different values.
3- How often do I apply where, group by or order by clauses on this column.

As the @Kasey answer states, for what's to see, you could add an index on the category column, but, it will depend on the number of different values you have for that column.